# Display the summed number for all the users

Tags: sql-server

How can I `sum(salary)` and display the summed number for all my users?

The resul of what i have from now gives this:

```
  FullName     AverageSalary    Seniority    SEN   ***[SUMofTheAverageSalary]*** - need

Fatima Alo      900                1          45             2400  
Omar Kutum     1000                2          55             2400
Sado Kerkzm     500                4          40             2400
```

Comment: I don't see the word `SUM` on your query.  Of course it doesn't work.

Comment: You can lookup `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.  Your question is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT user, SUM(Salary) AS Salary
FROM USERPANEL
GROUP BY user
```